# Using pycurl to login and retrieve cookie

Tags: python, pycurl

I found something similar to something I want to do using urllib2 here: [How to use Python to login to a webpage and retrieve cookies for later usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189555/how-to-use-python-to-login-to-a-webpage-and-retrieve-cookies-for-later-usage)

Their solution was :

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

username = 'myuser'
password = 'mypassword'

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'j_password' : password})
opener.open('http://www.example.com/login.php', login_data)
resp = opener.open('http://www.example.com/hiddenpage.php')
print resp.read()
```

I want something like this using pycurl if possible. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This looks a lot like a dupe of [Logging in and using cookies in pycurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221191/logging-in-and-using-cookies-in-pycurl). You give pycurl a path to a file to write cookies to with

```
c.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt')
```

and a path to read them from (probably the same) with

```
c.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt')
```